# Update a list (ObservableCollection) after instantiating it in the class constructor (MVVM e WINUI)

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I am faced with this situation and I don't know if I'm doing it right. I have a classic ViewModel that I use for CRUD operations. Is it a good practice to instantiate the collection each time with "new" in order to apply filters? (see the Task DoSearch at the end).
I wondered about this because I don't know what it means to generate new instances every time. Also because I had thought of creating the new record directly on the Grid by creating a record and filtering it to allow it to be edited and saved.

```
public class BlankViewModel : ObservableObject
{


    private readonly PersonDataContext _context;
    private Person? _selectedPerson;


    public BlankViewModel(PersonDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (!_context.People.Any())
        {
            _context.People.AddRange(new Person[]
            {
                        new Person{ Id=1, Cognome="A", Nome="B" },
                        new Person{ Id=2, Cognome="C", Nome="D" },
                        new Person{ Id=3, Cognome="E", Nome="F" }
            });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(_context.People);

        AddCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(DoAdd);
        RemoveCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(DoRemove, () => SelectedPerson != null);
        SaveCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(DoSave);
        SearchCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand<string>(DoSearch!);
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Person> people;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get => people;
        set => SetProperty(ref people, value);
    }


    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get => _selectedPerson!;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedPerson, value);
            RemoveCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public IRelayCommand AddCommand
    {
        get;
    }
    public IRelayCommand RemoveCommand
    {
        get;
    }
    public IRelayCommand SaveCommand
    {
        get;
    }
    public IRelayCommand<string> SearchCommand
    {
        get;
    }


    private async Task DoAdd()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        //to DO ??


    }

    private async Task DoRemove()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson != null)
        {
            people.Remove(SelectedPerson);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(People));

            _context.People.Remove(SelectedPerson);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            SelectedPerson = null!;
        }
    }

    private async Task DoSave()
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private async Task DoSearch(string textToSearch)
    {
        people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(await _context.People.Where(x => x.Cognome.Contains(textToSearch)).ToListAsync());
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(People));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to instantiate the collection each time with "new" in order to apply filters? (see the Task DoSearch at the end)

I'd just create a new `List` for the UI using each instance in the source data.

Here's one way to do this.

**Note**: Just to show you different options,

- This sample is implemented in different ways to use the **CommunityToolkit**.
- This sample uses an interface **IPersonService** instead of passing the context directly.

**PersonService.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinUI3Tests;

public record Person(int Id, string Cognome, string Nome);

public interface IPersonService
{
    Task<IReadOnlyList<Person>> GetPeople();

    Task<bool> Remove(Person person);
}

public class FakePersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly List<Person> people = new()
    {
        new Person(Id: 1, Cognome: "A", Nome: "B"),
        new Person(Id: 2, Cognome: "C", Nome: "D"),
        new Person(Id: 3, Cognome: "E", Nome: "F"),
    };

    public Task<IReadOnlyList<Person>> GetPeople()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<IReadOnlyList<Person>>(this.people);
    }

    public async Task AddRange(IEnumerable<Person> people)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        this.people.AddRange(people);
    }

    public Task SaveChanges()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<bool> Remove(Person person)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(this.people.Remove(person));
    }
}
```

**BlankViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace WinUI3Tests;

public partial class BlankViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private IPersonService? personService;

    public async Task SetPersonService(IPersonService personService)
    {
        this.personService = personService;
        People = await this.personService.GetPeople();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private IEnumerable<Person>? people;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Person? selectedPerson;

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Add()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        // to DO ??
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Remove()
    {
        if (this.personService is not null &&
            SelectedPerson != null)
        {
            _ = this.personService.Remove(SelectedPerson);
            People = await this.personService.GetPeople();
            SelectedPerson = null!;
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Save()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Search(string textToSearch)
    {
        if (this.personService is not null)
        {
            People = (await this.personService.GetPeople())
                .Where(x => x.Cognome.Contains(textToSearch));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinUI3Tests;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await ViewModel.SetPersonService(new FakePersonService());
    }

    public BlankViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3Tests.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3Tests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="TextToSearchTextBox" />
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddCommand}"
                Content="Add" />
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.RemoveCommand}"
                Content="Remove" />
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Bind TextToSearchTextBox.Text, Mode=OneWay}"
                Content="Search" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.People, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the application environment and requirements. If you are  writing a desktop app with the data stored locally (e.g. Sqlite), or if the data is very seldom updated, or if database queries are very slow for some reason, then you could reasonably keep your in-memory copy up to date and not re-query every time.

In most other cases, however, it would make sense to re-query before key operations such as Add, Remove, Modify because then the user will be able to see what the most recent data is before making the change.

Typically the re-query would be done as part of the UI switching to a different page, for example moving from the main page to a page that displays the Add, Remove or Modify dialog.

In the case of Add you might let them do the Add based on stale data and then address the possibility of a name collision if/when it happens (you need to handle that situation anyway even if you have shown the user the most recent data, because the data in the database may have been updated between the time of your query and the time of the user's save).

Comment: Yes, I use SQLIte. But the question is if, for apply the filter, it 's correct call NEW ObservableCollection each time.   Thanks for your answare @sjb-sjb

Comment: The constructor for ObservableCollection just allocates storage and then Add()s each member of the source enumerable. So in terms of the work done the two choices are fairly similar. I would probably use Clear() on the existing list and then Add each element of the query results. Which way is faster would depend on the query results.

Comment: ``ObservableCollection`` notifies the UI each time you add an item. It'd be better if could do **AddRange()** but unfortunately we can't (yet?). If you are adding a bunch of items in one time, you might want to consider a new ``ObservableCollection``.

Comment: True, a good point. If you use the constructor that takes the source list then you might avoid a lot of notifications.

Comment: This is why we need ``AddRange`` in ``ObservableCollection`` but we just have to sit and wait.

Comment: Even though the OP in this question refers to ObservableCollection, and the accepted answer uses IEnumerable, there are many controls such as NavigationView, ListView, TreeView where an ordered collection or IList is needed. ObservableCollection is an insufficient answer in those situations because it is not ordered. Assigning the list, instead of clearing and adding to it, supports the required notification without using an observable list -- a plain old List will do. For other ops such as Remove, you have to either re-query or else re-assign the IList variable after removing the element.